# Transacciones mysql

Tags: mysql, transacciones

Buen día, tengo una consulta:
Si estoy trabajando con transacciones en mysql y dentro de la transacción inserto, modifico y elimino registros, la transacción me bloquea la tabla completa, o solo los registros que estoy afectando?
El aislamiento de la base de datos esta en "REPEATABLE-READ"

Comment: Depende.. leiste la documentacion? algo en particular no entendiste?

Comment: Es que tenemos una BD que realiza operaciones por medio de transacciones, pero estas me están bloqueando las tablas y hacen muy lento el proceso, ya que hasta que las transacciones no se terminan, por alguna razón no me consulta la información o tarda más de lo normal

Comment: Por eso te pregunto.. en la documentacion esta explicado cuando se bloquea y como se bloquea.. vuelvo a preguntar (porque no tenemos idea ni que haces en las transacciones, ni cuantos registros o tablas se ven impactados, ni nada) leiste la documentacion y algo no entendiste?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el aislamiento entre las transacciones, y cual debo aplicar en este caso, ya que, en las transacciones puedo estar afectando hasta tres o cuatro tablas y siendo este el caso necesitaría que se bloquee únicamente los registros afectados y no toda la tabla.

Comment: ¿Por qué has establecido el nivel de aislamiento a repeatable read? ¿Qué versión y motor de escritura estás utilizando?

Comment: Es el que venia por defecto en el vps que contratamos, estamos trabajando con mysql 5.7.31 desde node js

Answer (score 1):

Depende bastante del tipo de base de datos y la versión que seleccionaste. Por ejemplo **InnoDB** implementa el standar de row-level en 2 tipos ***shared*** y ***exclusive***. Así mismo debes verificar si tienes activado el **AUTOCOMMIT** que por omisión siempre tiene el valor de **1** lo que significa que esta activado, esto quiere decir que por cada **update** aunque tengas el **commit** al final del script, se estan **commitendo** los cambios.

Mas [info1](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29312), [info2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html)

Comment: No entendí como se pude hacer para definir si una transacción será shared o exclusive, sin embargo, el AUTOCOMMIT se inhabilita cuando ejecuto el START TRANSACTION

Comment: si es la razón por la cual lo deberías desactivar.